# Expand a JSON string when serializing an object in Jackson

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

I am working on a Java Spring project where I have to convert an object to json. But there is one string field x that i want to transform before json conversion.  The field `x`, which is a deserialized JSON string like `[['a','b'], ['c','d']`. The object is a model read from the db using jpa data, it looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Myobject implements Serializable {
    @JsonSerialize(using = x.class)
    private String x; //x is a json string like "[['a','b'], ['c','d']"
}
```

Whats the best way to expand the `String` x , so that the result looks like:

```
{
  "x": [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]
}
```

Note that in the json the value of `x` is no longer a string, but a 2d array.
One way i hate to do is to write a customer sterilizer, in which i convert the string x to a 2d array, and then write my own serilizer for the 2d array and push element one by one. There has to be a better way to do this, no?

```
@Override
public void serialize(String x, JsonGenerator jGenerator, SerializerProvider provider)
        throws IOException {
}
```

I have looked a lot of places but didn't find the answer.

Comment: You cant assign 2d int array to String, Use x as 2d int array. convert json String to 2d array,  assign that 2d array to x and rest jackson will handle, no need to add a custom serializer.

Comment: i have no power to change x - its a string column read from the database. should i create another object that transform x from string to array? whats the best way to handle such transformation in spring?

Comment: solved thru using JPA converter.